# TFS database is becoming Huge

Tags: tfs

My TFS DB Has become very big and growing very fast in the couple of months.

The query to find attachmentTypes gave the following results.
Query:

```
use Tfs_DefaultCollection 

select  a.attachmenttype, sum(f.compressedlength)/1024/1024 as sizeInMB from dbo.tbl_Attachment as a 

inner join tbl_File as f on a.TfsFileId=f.FileId

inner join tbl_testrun as tr on a.testrunid=tr.testrunid 

inner join tbl_project as p on p.projectid=tr.projectid

group by a.attachmenttype

order by sum(f.compressedlength) desc
```

Result:

```
IntermediateCollectorData:420836
GeneralAttachment:458
TmiTestRunDeploymentFiles:122
BugFilingData:26
CodeCoverage:6
AfnStrip:4
TmiTestResultDetail:0
TmiTestRunSummary:0
TestImpactDetails:0
```

What is IntermediateCollectorData? Is there any way I can control TFS from creating so much IntermediateCollectorData and how do I delete it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/232c7fcd-da1f-4056-a5a6-892f14591e62/my-tfs-db-became-huge?forum=tfsgeneral) these are trace entries. Guy deleted them with test attachment cleaner.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400788(v=vs.90).aspx):

> Trace allows you to record real-time information about application
>   execution and performance and can be used to help diagnose problems
>   occurring on the server. Although useful for diagnosing problems,
>   enabling tracing should only be used for troubleshooting as it can
>   have an adverse effect on server performance.

[Here](http://larzjoakimnilzzon.blogspot.com/2012/04/tracelogging-configuration-in-team.html) is the guide to enable tracing. You can most likely just set it up to false instead of true and disable it that way.

Also 400GB isn't that much in todays standard. Creating Labels for few months will take a more space.